# checking number of connections used by data source : Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, connection, datasource, ibm-was

Is there any way to check the number of connections used by data source?

I am getting connectionwaittimeout exception in my web application, so to check which function is utilizing more connections or not releasing any connection I want to check the number of connections used by data source at any point.

Comment: Which version of WAS are you using (Liberty or classic?)? If you are using classic WAS then you have PMI (performance monitoring infrastructure) available in the web admin console.

Comment: Yes I can see PMI,,,,how can I use it to check the connections used by data source

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the implementation of your DataSource you probably can have access to some configurable property. For example the [BasicDataSource.removedAbandonned](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html#setRemoveAbandoned(boolean)) from apache-commons allows to reclaim a connection back to the pool if it has been utilized for too long.
But of course you should go back to your code and make sure any manually borrowed Connections are properly closed in a try-catch-finally block (or the new [Java 7 try-with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax)

Comment: I am using java 6 in my web app....what should I do to get the number of connections at any point using the DataSource class object

Answer (score 0):

In the WebSphere Application Server you have at least two features that may help you:

1) PMI (Performance monitoring infrastructure)
You can enable various counters on your Datasoruce and monitor it. See [JDBC counters](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rprf_datacounter2.html?lang=en) for more details. The most useful for me are `FreePoolSize`, `PercentUsed` to see the pool utilization, `WaitingThreadCount` and `WaitTime` to see if any threads are waiting and how long, `JDBCTime` and `UseTime` to see whats the average query time in comparison to the time the connection is being held.

2) Connection leak detection

WebSphere contains trace settings that will allow you to dump connection pool when ConnectionWaitTimoutException appear. See following pdf for detailed description how to configure and use it - [Understanding and Resolving ConnectionWaitTimeoutExceptions](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039259&aid=1)